# How can I access the value of a nested vue.js component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nested, vue-component

I have a component called `lbcontainer` and a second component called `lbitem`.

Now I want to nest any number of `lbitem` components into one `lbcontainer` component.

The `lbcontainer` component has a method that should access all `lbitem` components that I have nested in the `lbcontainer` component.

Problem is: with `ref` I can get to the item via `this.$ref.lbitem`, but this only works in the component declaration, but not when I use the component later in HTML.

```
Vue.component('lbcontainer', {
    methods: {
    "showChildren": function() {
        console.log(this.$refs);
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
      <a @click='showChildren'>Show children</a>
    </div>
  `
});

Vue.component('lbitem', {
    data: function() {
    return {
        value: ""
    }
  },
  template: `
    <input v-model="value"></span>
  `
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {

  },
  methods: {

  }
});
```

```
<div id="app">
  <lbcontainer>
    <lbitem ref="item"></lbitem>
    <lbitem ref="item"></lbitem>
  </lbcontainer>
</div>
```

When I press the button the `console.log` shows an empty object. How can I access the nested children?

[Here is jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndLf3h6p/)

Comment: what exactly do you need to access ? the vue way to get values from a child is to have that child emit the value and have the parent listen on that.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding using $ref in vue ...
( $ref is populated after the first render...)

child can only communicate with their parent by event ...
or parent have all data and send to their child by props.

if parent and chidrend have to edit the data you can use v-model or .sync;

https://codesandbox.io/s/p95x1mxykm